# How can I get the custom id of the submit button clicked using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been trying to call in a php variable into a jquery submit onclick event in such a way that when a reply is submitted, the id of the comment is captured to be processed by an ajax code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    var rname = $("#rname").val();
    var remail = $("#remail").val();
    var rmessage = $("#rmessage").val();
    var cid = $("#cid").val();
    var post_id = $("#post_id").val();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit'.$commnt_id.'" value="Reply This Comment" class="primary-btn text-uppercase" />
```

Comment: did you tried the solutions??

Answer (score 1):

There are so many options to achieve this:

**Solution 1 (by using data attribute):**

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" data-commentID="<?=$commnt_id?>" value="Reply This Comment" class="primary-btn text-uppercase myBtnClass"/>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myBtnClass").click(function(){
        var commentId = $(this).attr('data-commentID');
    }); 
});
```

**Solution 2 (by using onclick event):**

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="mymethodCall(<?=$commnt_id?>)"  value="Reply This Comment" class="primary-btn text-uppercase"/>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function mymethodCall(commentId){
    console.log(commentId);
}
```

In solution 1, using class name `myBtnClass` will help you, if you have multiple records.

**Running Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".myBtnClass").click(function(){
        var commentId = $(this).attr('data-commentID');
        alert(commentId);
   }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" name="submit" data-commentID="1" value="Reply This Comment" class="primary-btn text-uppercase myBtnClass"/>
```

**Running Example 2:**

```js
function mymethodCall(commentId){
 console.log(commentId);
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="mymethodCall(1)"  value="Reply This Comment" class="primary-btn text-uppercase"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.id`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='submit']").click(function(e){
        console.log(this.id);
    });
 });
```

Also, when you use `$("#submit")` you're selecting the elements where the id is equal to `submit` instead of the elements that have the type equal to `submit`.

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nrmwx315/

Comment: Or is same as `this.id`

Answer (score 0):

May can rewrite to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" data-comment-id="'.$commnt_id.'"
```

and in js:

```
$('[name="submit"]').click(function(e){
        console.log($(this).data('comment-id'));
```

Comment: `$("#submit")` doesn't exist